# Как отменить измениения из git pull?

Tags: git

Вот такая ситуация, когда я делаю `pull` с удаленого репо я хочу знать какие изменения я стягиваю, для этого я выполняю такую команду `git pull --no-commit`
таким образом все стягивается но комит не делается.

Далее я выполняю такую команду `git status` и вижу какие файлы собираются закомититься и вот тут самое интересное, если я вижу, что есть файл который меня интересует был изменен то я выполняю команду `gitk`.

Открывается интерфейс в котором можно увидеть что было изменено в конкретном файле и вот вопрос

Если в этом файле изменения которые я не хочу принимать как мне отменить эти изменения?

Надеюсь получилось обьяснить, что хочу) Если, что то не получилось - спрашивайте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз файлы "собираются закоммититься", значит они уже "были добавлены". И git status сам все расскажет.

```
git reset HEAD <имя файла>
```

убрать файл с коммита.

```
git reset -p HEAD <имя файла>
```

убрать изменения "по кусочкам". git будет показывать маленькие куски изменений и спрашивать, нужно ли их убрать.

кстати, запускать gitk, что бы посмотреть изменения не обязательно. Можно просто так

```
git diff --staged <имя файла>
```

если имя файла не указывать, то будут показаны все изменения для коммита. Вместо `--staged` можно писать `--cached` - это синонимы.

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать Git Gui то в нужном вам файле можно выделить участок кода, который вы не хотите добавлять и отменить именно его для добавления в коммит.